# Is it bad practice to define an array as part of a function call?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Working with WordPress and looking at code examples, I've seen two different ways of using arrays with functions:

**1. Define the array first, then pass it into the function as a parameter**

```
$args = array(
    'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>', 
 );
register_sidebar( $args );
```

**2. Define the array as part of the function call**

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>', 
 ) );
```

Is it bad practice to define an array as part of a function call (**#2**) or is it a style choice?

If it's bad practice, why?

Comment: how is it specific to wordpress in any way?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about either, but I'd prefer the first. In the grand scheme of things though this is trivial. More importantly, this isn't a WordPress question, it's barely even a PHP question, it's a generic programming question, and would be better on stack overflow

Comment: @TomJNowell Okay, sure. Didn't know if there was some WP coding style I should be following (hence the question) but also I'm not sure what kind of garbage disposal PHP or WordPress has so that's why I went there first.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but 1st option (if written in global namespace) the variable won't be destroyed untill script finish while 2nd option the parameter will be destroyed at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it's not bad practice.**

If you are going to reuse the array you have to choose the first possibilty. Otherwise the choise is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

No choice is bad practice, it is all about readability. I personally prefer choice #1 due to readability.

This is purely just a case of what works best for you. Just a note on #2, just for readability, I would rewrite it as

```
register_sidebar( 
    [
        'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id'            => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>', 
    ]
);
```

### EDIT

Note: The above array syntax (*[]*) is only available as from PHP 5.4. If you happen to use older versions (*which you really shouldn't*), change the short array syntax back to the old syntax (*array()*)

Comment: Note that the `[]` array syntax requires PHP 5.4 or later. (Which you should be using, but in the event you aren't…)

Comment: @duskwuff I know this is PHP 5.4 syntax. *but in the event you aren't…*, then you surely want to be hacked in the very near future. One can't keep on doing stuff the crappy old way just because there are still hosts and users who are stuck with the dinosaurs. What really is the use of having all these great features and syntax and not using it

Comment: Agreed! I'm simply pointing this out so that anyone unfortunate enough to be on PHP 5.3 or earlier will know why they're getting that syntax error.